# Generar proyecto VS de SFML

Tags: visual-studio

He descargado la librería gráfica SFML y se supone que viene preparada para generar un proyecto en Visual Studio con CMake, pero no consigo hacerlo correctamente. ¿Alguna sugerencia? como alternativa ¿alguien sabe dónde puedo encontrar un fichero Lua de configuración para Genie?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCIONADO**

Me he percatado que la versión que proporciona la web oficial de [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.4.1/) no contiene el fichero *CMakeLists*, sin embargo he encontrado la misma versión en un repositorio de GitHub en el que le han incluido dicho [fichero](http://www.sfml-dev.org/files/SFML-2.4.1-windows-vc14-32-bit.zip) para CMake. He ejecutado la última versión de [CMake GUI](https://cmake.org/files/v3.7/cmake-3.7.0-win32-x86.zip), seleccionado el directorio de SFML y configurado la aplicación para Visual Studio 14 2015 y este ha generado la solución sin problemas.